# How to hide the left tool bar of content type for non admin people?

Tags: toolbar

I want to hide the left tool bar of content type also revision message box, as shown in attachement, for non admin people.

I have gone through following https://www.drupal.org/node/1276698 but it's only for particular content.

Please suggest me how to hide from all content.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `yourwebsite.com/admin/people/permissions` check that the following permission are unchecked **under Node** (click image to enlarge)

[image]

**Edit:** I did testing, and it's the Administer Content, make sure you uncheck it! Also administer content types as you don't want them to have that either.

Comment: if i uncheck all of those, authenticated user[non admin] cannot able to create content, i want them to create but only thing  i just want to hide that tool bar for non admin, though they can create content.

Comment: @rose you see the 2nd last row on my screenshot that says Article Create new Content, u need to check mark that one, also for Edit and Delete own content, if you want to allow them to do that as well.

Comment: I assume its the Article content type, if it's for another content type it should be listed further down.

Comment: @rose, one last thing. make sure you allowed them edit and delete **own content and not any content**. With any content they can edit or delete anyone else content and you may not want that.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer according updated question:**

Use this function in `template.php`.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function THEMENAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  global $user;
  $is_administrator = in_array('administrator', array_values($user->roles));

  if($form_id == 'my_form_id'){
    // if $user does NOT have the administrator role.
    if (!$is_administrator) {
      // disable vertical tabs for this form
      form_disable_vertical_tabs($form);
    }
  }
}
```

**Answer before updating question:**

You may use this snippet in `page.tpl` of your currently active theme.

```
global $user;
$roleid = paste_role_id_of_admin; //
if(user_has_role($roleid, $user)) {
  <?php print $sidebar_first; ?>
}
```

OR

```
if($is_admin){
  <?php print $sidebar_first; ?>
}
```

Comment: where exactly i can add this above code, in which function?

Comment: In no function. In your `page.tpl.php` in your current theme.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to look at the [Simplify](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplify) module for this. Here is a quote from its project page:

> Simplify allows particular fields to be hidden from the user interface. This helps to de-clutter forms and present a more user-friendly experience to content editors.